# How to restrict the wild card route

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
get '/:company' => 'organizations#show', as: 'company_home'
```

I have this route, this is a way so that different companies registered to my application will login. As I have overridden all the devise related things. This is working fine until I have realized that for every route, this is getting applied

When I hit

```
 get 'employee_dashboard' => 'dashboard#show'
```

The Parameters: {"company"=>"employee_dashboard"} are going to `organizations#show`

But I want it to hit `dashboard#show` how to get around with this?

Comment: Change the order the directive are placed in the `config/routes.rb`. Put `get 'employee_dashboard' => 'dashboard#show'` above the other directive

Comment: You can either put above or you can have two level route like `get '/company/:company`. this will actually i think is better just to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the wildcard route after

```
get 'employee_dashboard' => 'dashboard#show'
```

or at the end of route file

```
get '/:company' => 'organizations#show', as: 'company_home'
```

so this route will be used only if no other route matches